# Check OpenSSH version and update instructions on FreeBSD system

Tags: ssh, freebsd

On a FreeBSD system (8.1), I am looking for instructions on how to check the running version of OpenSSH and also instructions on the best way to download install an update of OpenSSH

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Run `sshd -V` or `ssh -V` and they'll return the version and usage information.
Note: These are capital "V" now, when I originally wrote this answer they were lower case.

There's a dozen ways to upgrade.

- `pkg-add -r openssh-portable`
- `cd /usr/ports/security/openssh && make install clean`
- `portupgrade security/openssh-portable`
- part of the makeworld/buildworld process
- freebsd-upgrade
- and the list goes on...

I'm not aware of any issues with the 5.2p1 version that shipped with 8.1-RELEASE. I have seen hoax e-mails flying around for over a year now announcing the imminent release of a zero day hack (note that it's been a year and a half since release, so 'zero' day was a heck of a long time ago).

Comment: Agree with everything, except 8.1-RELEASE has OpenSSH 5.4p1.

Comment: I needed to use `ssh -V` (note capital v) as on my system (and I thought this was standard) the `-v` option is used for verbose (iirc).

Comment: @MikeH-R Thanks, not sure when it changed, but it's definitely capital V now.

Answer (score 5):

```
telnet localhost 22
```

Why do you want to upgrade OpenSSH? It's part of the core system and is usually upgraded with the system.

Comment: This assumes your running the daemon.

Comment: Awesome answer.  Exactly what I was looking for.  I always run the daemon

Answer (score 4):

## How to find openssh version on a Linux or Unix-like system?

The syntax is as follows to find openssh version on a CentOS/RHEL/SL:

```
# yum list installed openssh\*
```

The syntax is as follows to find openssh version on a Debian/Ubuntu Linux:

```
$ dpkg --list | grep openssh
### OR ###
$ dpkg --list openssh\*
```

[image: Sample output]

Answer (score 3):

Try running:

```
which sshd
```

If that prints /usr/sbin/sshd, then it's probably installed as a package.  In that case, you can check the installed version using:

```
pkg_info | grep ssh
```

or:

```
pkg_info -W `type sshd`
```

And I think you update it using:

```
pkg_add -r openssh-portable
```

but read the [FreeBSD Guide to the Packages System](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/packages-using.html) first, because I haven't done that in a long time and it might have changed.

If

```
which sshd
```

prints /usr/local/sbin/sshd, then it's probably installed as a port.

Read up on how to upgrade it in the [Guide to Using the Ports System](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/ports-using.html).  The port name is security/openssh-portable, i.e. /usr/ports/security/openssh-portable.

Comment: Of course, if you really wanted the running version rather than the installed version, you could also try "telnet localhost 22", and look for the version number.  The version number is the second number, i.e. the number after "OpenSSH_".

Comment: See also http://www.geekvenue.net/chucktips/jason/chuck/1044986336/index_html